# Unit testing of callback methods in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing

Can someone explain to me whether it needs to write Unit testing for Hibernate callback methods? I meant methods of Entity with annotation @PrePresist, @PreUpdate and etc.

Here is a slice of my Entity class with needed fields. I meant fields "startDate" and "endDate". As you can see there are certain logics in methods prePersistStartDate and prePersistEndDate that determine which values will be set on. So my question was about a necessity to created Unit tests for such methods.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Budget")
public class Budget implements Serializable, Comparable<Budget> {
  // *** Fields *** //

  @Transient
  private Calendar initCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private Integer id;

  ...
  ...
  ...

  @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
  @Column(name = "range", length = 15, nullable = false)
  private Range range;

  @Column(name = "by_date_range")
  private Boolean byDateRange;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  @Column(name = "start_date", nullable = false)
  private Date startDate;

  /**
   * Set up value for start date.
   */
  @PrePersist
  @PreUpdate
  public void prePersistStartDate() {
    if (!byDateRange) {
      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      calendar.setTimeInMillis(initCalendar.getTimeInMillis());

      switch (range) {
        case CURRENT_WEEK:
          // set Monday as the start day of week (value = 2)
          calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 2 - calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
          break;

        case LAST_WEEK:
          // subtract one week
          calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, -1);
          // set Monday as the start day of week (value = 2)
          calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 2 - calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
          break;

        case CURRENT_MONTH:
          // set first day of the current Month
          calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
          break;

        case LAST_MONTH:
          // subtract one month
          calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
          // set first day of the last Month
          calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
          break;

        case CURRENT_YEAR:
          // set first day of the current Year
          calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
          break;

        case LAST_YEAR:
          // subtract one year
          calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
          // set first day of the last Year
          calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
          break;

        default:
      }

      startDate = calendar.getTime();
    }
  }

  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  @Column(name = "end_date", nullable = false)
  private Date endDate;

  /**
   * Set up value for end date.
   */
  @PrePersist
  @PreUpdate
  public void prePersistEndDate() {
    if (!byDateRange) {
      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      calendar.setTimeInMillis(initCalendar.getTimeInMillis());

      switch (range) {
        case CURRENT_WEEK:
          // set the last day of the current week
          calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 7 - calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
          break;

        case LAST_WEEK:
          // subtract one week
          calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, -1);
          // set the last day of the current week
          calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 7 - calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
          break;

        case CURRENT_MONTH:
          // set last day of the current Month
          calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.MONTH));
          break;

        case LAST_MONTH:
          // subtract one month
          calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
          // set last day of the last Month
          calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.MONTH));
          break;

        case CURRENT_YEAR:
          // set last day of the current Year
          calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.YEAR));
          break;

        case LAST_YEAR:
          // subtract one year
          calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
          // set last day of the last Year
          calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.YEAR));
          break;

        default:
      }

      endDate = calendar.getTime();
    }
  }

  public enum Range {
    CURRENT_WEEK, LAST_WEEK, CURRENT_MONTH, LAST_MONTH, CURRENT_YEAR, LAST_YEAR
  }
}
```

Comment: I am still working on it and can provide it little later. My method will be set on the date in filed and this value will depend on two another fields in the same Entity. Actually logic won't be complex but I just want to know this is practiced or not?

Comment: please complete ur question with ur code, and call me when it was ready. i am interested.

Comment: Hi, the code has been provided, could you please take a look at it.